# How to change the DB table column order using Spring + Sping Data JPA + Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

actually i am trying to learn something using this tutorial -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SGDpanrc8U&t=2027s

Now i connect my new DB with my Sping(Java) something.
But. I don't understand why in RUN output in IJ and SQL Shell shows wrong order of lines.
**The first line in column should be ID.
After should go - name,email, date,age.**

In reality it shows - age,date,id,email,name. How can i change it? Please, help.

Example from SQL Shell -

```
 Column |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 age    | integer                |           |          |
 dob    | date                   |           |          |
 id     | bigint                 |           | not null |
 email  | character varying(255) |           |          |
 name   | character varying(255) |           |          |
Indexes:
    "student_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

My Student class -

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Student {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "student_sequence",
            sequenceName = "student_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "student_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private LocalDate dob;
    private Integer age;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(Long id, String name, String email, LocalDate dob, Integer age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Student(String name, String email, LocalDate dob, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.age = age;
    }

Getters,Setters and to String
```

I try to change long to Long and nothing else. I don't know how to change order of lines here. It looks like everything is fine.

Comment: Why do you want it on order?

Comment: Why not if it can be displayed in some default order that a person prefer to see ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you configure Hibernate to auto-generate and create the table schema by setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `create-drop`. It has its own rule to determine the order of the columns in the generated create tables DDL which the has nothing to do with the order of fields in the related entity Java class.

Since hibernate 6.2 , it provides a way to customize the column order in the generated DDL through `ColumnOrderingStrategy` but the behaviour you want still not support out of the box.

If you want to take back the total control about defining the column order in the tables , you have to manually create the table by yourself rather than rely on Hibernate to do it. You have to set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `none` to tell Hibernate not to do that.

*Note: consider to use the DB schema management tool such as [`Flyway`](https://flywaydb.org/) or [`Liquibase`](https://www.liquibase.org/) to manage all schema changes for any serious production application.*

Comment: IMO, the expectation to find PK column at the first position is reasonable, regardless whether it makes sense in SQL or not.